# How to convert a <div> to collapsable panel?

Tags: javascript, html

As shown in the image below I want to collapse left blue panel

[image]

I am trying to create left Blue panel using HTML. But I do not have any idea, how to create collapsable panel?

Comment: What have you tried so far, can you update your question with code you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you a div and a button. By default, the div is collapsed but when you click the button, the div will expand to reveal the content. Clicking the button again will collapse it again.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="panel-toggle">Panel Button</a>
<div class="blue-panel">a blue panel</div>
```

CSS:

```
.blue-panel{overflow:hidden; max-height: 0;}

.blue-panel.active{max-height: 1000px;}
```

JS:

```
jQuery('.panel-toggle').click(function() {
    jQuery('.blue-panel').toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: have you seen jQuery in the question ?

Comment: jQuery is a Javascript library is it not? The author has tagged Javascript and HTML so I've posted a quick and easy solution to his problem.

Comment: Does the tag jQuery exist or not ? is it present or not ?

Comment: If you want to be pedantic about it, no. It's says Javascript but I imagine that given the lack of other answers and the general ease of jQuery implementation then the author may find this helpful. Feel free to contribute your own solution instead of trolling. Have a nice day.

Comment: @Anonymous0day is right, we can't assume that the OP knows how to use jquery.

Answer (score 1):

**Concept used**

Execute a function when button is clicked.

**Explanation of Code**

First there are 2 buttons present on same location : myButton1 and myButton2

myButton2 which shows the div is currently invisible (display:none;).

when mybutton1 is clicked it reduces the width of "menu" div and also hides itself while making myButton2 visible. When myButton2 is clicked it restores the width of "menu" div and hides itself while making button1 visible.

```js
function toggle1() {
  document.getElementById("menu").style.width = "2px";
  document.getElementById("myButton1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("myButton2").style.display = "block";

};
function toggle2() {
  document.getElementById("menu").style.width = "100px";
  document.getElementById("myButton2").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("myButton1").style.display = "block";

};
```

```css
#menu {
  width: 100px;
  height: 500px;
  background: blue;
}
#myButton1 {
  position: absolute;
}
#myButton2 {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <input onclick="toggle1()" type="button" value="hide" id="myButton1"></input>
  <input onclick="toggle2()" type="button" value="show" id="myButton2"></input>
  <div id="menu">

  </div>
</div>
```